# Are there any academic papers/books about hacking wargames?

Tags: web-application, ctf, academia, gaming

I'm looking for sources (academic papers, books, articles from notable magazines) that can be used as reference for a Bachelor's Thesis, that should be about making an educational, gamified hacking wargame, to be used in Ethical Hacking courses at the university.

Since it's a Bachelor's Thesis, there is a certain level of source quality requirement needed for a source to be considered a valid Reference for the thesis, and given the nature of wargames and hacking culture, it's not easy to find.

So, does anyone know about any good reference that I can use in a Bachelor's Thesis that is about wargames? Something more focused on the creation of said wargame. I don't supose there will be many, since random blog posts don't qualify, and I would be super glad about any kind of response.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, there are plenty of academic papers on the topic.**

Just use the right keywords. The term *wargame* isn't as common for these competitions. But you'll find quite a few results combining the terms *CTF* and *security*, [e.g. on Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=ctf+security).

Here are some examples:

- [*Learning Cyber Security Through Gamification:*](http://www.indjst.org/index.php/indjst/article/view/67760)

  > **Objectives:** Introducing gaming approach in the jeopardy round of InCTF (Indian Capture the Flag). **Methods:** Present Jeopardy round of InCTF can be compared as take-away assignments, where participants are given set of questions to solve, this is aimed at testing their knowledge in various computer security concepts. To make jeopardy round more attractive and motivating to the students we introduce a gaming approach to it. A game is developed which is divided into various levels and at each level the knowledge of students in Cyber security concepts is tested. Our design will help others to host jeopardy round CTF and get maximum learning outcome from the students. **Findings:** Security competition like CTF (Capture the Flag) are effective tool in providing computer security training. **Conclusion:** Gaming approach in Cyber security education will be a big step forward in training more students in computer security and create a secure online world.
- [*Computer Security Competitions: Expanding Educational Outcomes:*](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6573297/)

  > Security competitions can be a lot of fun, and preparing for them often exposes participants to skills they might not otherwise have encountered. Yet, participating in such competitions doesn't necessarily provide a road map for future success. By offering enough feedback, organizers could turn competitions into valuable training opportunities, rather than simply opportunities for participants to self-assess their skills.
- [*Hacking Competitions and Their Untapped Potential for Security Education*](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5772962/)

There are also papers that focus specifically on the competition design, e.g.:

- [*The Design and Lessons of the ASCENT Security
  Teaching Lab*](https://isec.uta.edu/papers/ASCENT-labs.pdf)
- [*A security laboratory for CTF scenarios and teaching IDS*](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5529213/)